# I am using gradereport_user_get_grades_table moodle mobile webservice, Its retrieving the data in JSON format

Tags: angularjs, json

I am using a web service called gradereport_user_get_grades_table and executing it from the rest client,Its returning the data in the JSON format. My Question is how do i display the grade content value that is 10.0 in angular JS from the below JSON format.

```
{
  "tables": [{
    "courseid": 8,
    "userid": 14,
    "userfullname": "bhavani Rayappanavar",
    "maxdepth": 2,
    "tabledata": [{
      "itemname": {
        "class": "level1 levelodd oddd1 b1b b1t column-itemname",
        "colspan": 7,
        "content": "CategoryPhysics",
        "celltype": "th",
        "id": "cat_8_14"
      },
      "leader": {
        "class": "level1 levelodd oddd1 b1t b2b b1l column-leader",
        "rowspan": 3
      }
    }, {
      "itemname": {
        "class": "level2 leveleven item b1b column-itemname",
        "colspan": 1,
        "content": "Quizquiz",
        "celltype": "th",
        "id": "row_164_14"
      },
      "weight": {
        "class": "level2 leveleven item b1b itemcenter  column-weight",
        "content": "100.00 %",
        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_164_14 weight"
      },
      "grade": {
        "class": "level2 leveleven item b1b itemcenter  column-grade",
        "content": "10.00",
        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_164_14 grade"
      },
      "range": {
        "class": "level2 leveleven item b1b itemcenter  column-range",
        "content": "0–10",
        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_164_14 range"
      },
      "percentage": {
        "class": "level2 leveleven item b1b itemcenter  column-percentage",
        "content": "100.00 %",
        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_164_14 percentage"
      },
      "feedback": {
        "class": "level2 leveleven item b1b feedbacktext column-feedback",
        "content": " ",
        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_164_14 feedback"
      },
      "contributiontocoursetotal": {
        "class": "level2 leveleven item b1b itemcenter  column-contributiontocoursetotal",
        "content": "100.00 %",
        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_164_14 contributiontocoursetotal"
      }
    }, {
      "itemname": {
        "class": "level1 levelodd oddd1 baggt b2b column-itemname",
        "colspan": 1,
        "content": "NaturalCourse total",
        "celltype": "th",
        "id": "row_103_14"
      },
      "weight": {
        "class": "level1 levelodd oddd1 baggt b2b itemcenter  column-weight",
        "content": "-",
        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_103_14 weight"
      },
      "grade": {
        "class": "level1 levelodd oddd1 baggt b2b itemcenter  column-grade",
        "content": "10.00",
        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_103_14 grade"
      },
      "range": {
        "class": "level1 levelodd oddd1 baggt b2b itemcenter  column-range",
        "content": "0–10",
        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_103_14 range"
      },
      "percentage": {
        "class": "level1 levelodd oddd1 baggt b2b itemcenter  column-percentage",
        "content": "100.00 %",
        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_103_14 percentage"
      },
      "feedback": {
        "class": "level1 levelodd oddd1 baggt b2b feedbacktext column-feedback",
        "content": " ",
        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_103_14 feedback"
      },
      "contributiontocoursetotal": {
        "class": "level1 levelodd oddd1 baggt b2b itemcenter  column-contributiontocoursetotal",
        "content": "-",
        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_103_14 contributiontocoursetotal"
      }
    }]
  }],
  "warnings": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can display like below by assigning your json to a $scope variable and fetch using that

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Required data: {{name.tables[0].tabledata[1].grade.content}}</p>
  </body>
<script>
  
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = {
    "tables":
    [
        {
            "courseid": 8,
            "userid": 14,
            "userfullname": "bhavani Rayappanavar",
            "maxdepth": 2,
            "tabledata":
            [
                {
                    "itemname":
                    {
                        "class": "level1 levelodd oddd1 b1b b1t column-itemname",
                        "colspan": 7,
                        "content": "CategoryPhysics",
                        "celltype": "th",
                        "id": "cat_8_14"
                    },
                    "leader":
                    {
                        "class": "level1 levelodd oddd1 b1t b2b b1l column-leader",
                        "rowspan": 3
                    }
                },
                {
                    "itemname":
                    {
                        "class": "level2 leveleven item b1b column-itemname",
                        "colspan": 1,
                        "content": "Quizquiz",
                        "celltype": "th",
                        "id": "row_164_14"
                    },
                    "weight":
                    {
                        "class": "level2 leveleven item b1b itemcenter  column-weight",
                        "content": "100.00 %",
                        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_164_14 weight"
                    },
                    "grade":
                    {
                        "class": "level2 leveleven item b1b itemcenter  column-grade",
                        "content": "10.00",
                        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_164_14 grade"
                    },
                    "range":
                    {
                        "class": "level2 leveleven item b1b itemcenter  column-range",
                        "content": "0–10",
                        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_164_14 range"
                    },
                    "percentage":
                    {
                        "class": "level2 leveleven item b1b itemcenter  column-percentage",
                        "content": "100.00 %",
                        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_164_14 percentage"
                    },
                    "feedback":
                    {
                        "class": "level2 leveleven item b1b feedbacktext column-feedback",
                        "content": " ",
                        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_164_14 feedback"
                    },
                    "contributiontocoursetotal":
                    {
                        "class": "level2 leveleven item b1b itemcenter  column-contributiontocoursetotal",
                        "content": "100.00 %",
                        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_164_14 contributiontocoursetotal"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "itemname":
                    {
                        "class": "level1 levelodd oddd1 baggt b2b column-itemname",
                        "colspan": 1,
                        "content": "NaturalCourse total",
                        "celltype": "th",
                        "id": "row_103_14"
                    },
                    "weight":
                    {
                        "class": "level1 levelodd oddd1 baggt b2b itemcenter  column-weight",
                        "content": "-",
                        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_103_14 weight"
                    },
                    "grade":
                    {
                        "class": "level1 levelodd oddd1 baggt b2b itemcenter  column-grade",
                        "content": "10.00",
                        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_103_14 grade"
                    },
                    "range":
                    {
                        "class": "level1 levelodd oddd1 baggt b2b itemcenter  column-range",
                        "content": "0–10",
                        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_103_14 range"
                    },
                    "percentage":
                    {
                        "class": "level1 levelodd oddd1 baggt b2b itemcenter  column-percentage",
                        "content": "100.00 %",
                        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_103_14 percentage"
                    },
                    "feedback":
                    {
                        "class": "level1 levelodd oddd1 baggt b2b feedbacktext column-feedback",
                        "content": " ",
                        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_103_14 feedback"
                    },
                    "contributiontocoursetotal":
                    {
                        "class": "level1 levelodd oddd1 baggt b2b itemcenter  column-contributiontocoursetotal",
                        "content": "-",
                        "headers": "cat_8_14 row_103_14 contributiontocoursetotal"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "warnings":
    [
    ]
};
});

  
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: what u want to say??is it working as expected requirement or not?

Comment: Thanks alot, I have tried u r solution by executing below lines..  $scope.name = $mmaGrades.getGradesTable(8, 14);
 alert(name.tables[0].tabledata[1].grade.content);  May i know what is the issue with this code....Its not working..

Comment: first off all u need to call it like $scope.name.tables[0].tabledata[1].grade.content in your alert and  make sure that $mmaGrades.getGradesTable(8, 14);  returns the json you posted in your question....

Comment: For me it works by the following code alert($scope.names.tabledata[1].grade.content);

Comment: oh thats great...if you find this is helpfull please give me a upvote